# Are all child elements of a hyperlink node also links?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically, I have a large hyperlink element, with a background image. When the user hovers over it, I expose an edit button for them to click that pops up an input form for them to edit some stuff about the hyperlink.

For example, take photo albums. I display all of the user's photo albums with their cover photo and their name. Upon clicking the photo album, the user is relocated to another page with all of that album's contents. However, when they hover over the photo, this exposes an edit button above the bottom-right corner of the album. When they click this button, that exposes an edit form for them to edit the title of the album.

However, when they click the exposed edit button, this activates the link as well and they are transferred to the contents of that photo album. It does expose the edit form, but it doesn't matter since the page automatically transfers them to a different view.

How do I solve this? Are all child nodes of a hyperlink node also hyperlinked? And if so, how could I disable the hyperlinking mechanism for just that one edit button?

Comment: We are not a oracle. Show us some code.

Comment: Show your code. Simulate your problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if necessary.

Comment: You have to `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation and http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/.

```
$( elementThatOpensTheEditBox ).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // whatever code here to open the edit box
});
```

If the elements are dynamically generated, you can bind the click event using `.on`:

```
$('body').on('click', elementThatOpensTheEditBox, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // whatever code here to open the edit box
});
```

Comment: Hmmmmm, it seems to be because I'm generating my DOM tree from an AJAX function. I guess when I create that listener, it only applies to nodes which already exist?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do stopPropagation without a listener, rather, from inside a separate function that I'm calling onclick. I'm going to figure this out tomorrow.

Comment: @NateL See my updated code for dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery using event delegation (`$.on()`):

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" id="outer">
    <p>Click in the blue to follow the link</p>
    <p id="inner">I am inner to the link</p>
</a>

var $outer = $('#outer');

$outer.on('click', '#inner', function prevent(e){
    console.log('Inner clicked.');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fYPnu/2

And plain Javascript:

```
var inner = document.getElementById('inner');

inner.addEventListener('click', function prevent(e){
    console.log('Inner clicked.');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fYPnu/1

Note, for backwards compatibility with IE8<, you would need to detect for `.attachEvent()` as well.

Comment: I'm going to try this tomorrow. Thanks a ton. I always seem to have problems with jquery selectors. They seem to be quite finnicky.