# Prevent collapse of bootstrap collapsible element from click within a child of the collapser -- without event.stopPropagation()

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Less specifically, I want to find a way to prevent an event triggered within the child of the delegated listener element from triggering said listener. All the answers I have found related to this question say to use `event.stopPropagation()` to solve this or similar problems ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354713/are-all-child-elements-of-a-hyperlink-node-also-links#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354713/are-all-child-elements-of-a-hyperlink-node-also-links#_=_) , [How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open) , and others), but that causes an issue. If a bootstrap dropdown is open, any click outside of it is supposed to close it, but if the event propagation is stopped within the child element, it does not close that dropdown (that is an example of many bugs that could be created by `event.stopPropagation()`).

Here is my html:

```
<div id="collapser" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDiv">
    <p> Title of Section </p>
    <span> value </span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</div>
<div id="collapseDiv">
    <!-- collapsible content -->
</div>
```

I want to be able to click on the "value" span without toggling the collapse state of the collapsible div.

Thanks!

Comment: plz post jquery code also which you have tried so far

Comment: Sorry, I just removed the jquery tag. I haven't tried any jquery because I just wasn't sure where to go with it. I thought about using the `hide.bs.collapse` and `show.bs.collapse` events that are created, but I don't know how to cancel those only when the click happens on a certain element.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this. I am giving the answer based on requirements.

1. If the child element inside the div has no event or actions then you can simply add onclick="event.stopPropagation();. But remember this will disable any click functionality of the child element. This solution is helpful only when you want to prevent a portion of div to not collapse the entire div when clicked.
2. If the child element inside the div has some action on click then better would be move the element out of the div, which means we are taking the child element out of the collapse scope of div element and then use the CSS to move child element inside the div tag. This works for me everytime.

```html
<div data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse8" class="collapse-plus-minus-left card-title text-center">
   <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse8">SUB PROJECT</a>
</div>
<span class="add_span_button card-title text-center" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal_con" data-target="#myModal2" style="float:right; color:#007bff; cursor: pointer; position:relative; right:0px; bottom:32px">ADD</span>
```

To give example of 2nd solution, here in the below image, the when you click the ADD button, the SUB PROJECT div will not collapse. This is because ADD span is moved out of div and using the CSS it is displayed as if inside the div.
[image]